# what is the variable "data" storing in this java program?

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

My code is working. I just need to know about the role of a specific variable in the code.

I tried to print the value in the variable "data", but it gives me some numbers i cant understand.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream ("c:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\read.TXT");

    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\write.TXT");

    while (fileinputstream.available() > 0) {
        int data = fileinputstream.read();                                                       
        fileoutputstream.write(data);
    }

    fileinputstream.close();
    fileoutputstream.close();
}
```

Comment: `fileinputstream.available()` definitely not used correctly here.

Comment: Just read the Javadoc of that method. It reads the next byte from the stream, interpreted as `int`, from `0`to `255`. Thats what `data`stores.

Comment: `for( int data; (data = fileinputstream.read()) != -1; ) { fileoutputstream.write(data); }` would be a proper way to read the data. (Not tested.)

Comment: Note that this would be a great opportunity to become familiar with your step-by-step debugger, which would have been able to show you the different values the `data` variable holds at different steps of the execution. Lot of CS courses never really go into the topic of debuggers but they're a huge help, so I really encourage you to take a look at them if you haven't already

Comment: `it gives me some numbers i cant understand about` That's because you're reading in binary.  That's fine, and the file copy will work, but if you want to understand the data you have to convert it to a text character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) for `FileInputStream.read`, which says:

> Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

So the integer you got (i.e. the number stored in `data`) is the byte read from the file. Since your file is a text file, it is the ASCII value of the characters in that file (assuming your file is encoded in ASCII).

Comment: "Assuming your file is encoded in ASCII": Yes, but quite unlikely. But really there is no point in doing any processing with a text file (copying or dumping bytes AS IS excepted) if you don't know the character encoding.

Comment: @TomBlodget I know, but it becomes really hard for me to satisfactorily explain what the bytes are when the file uses a encoding they uses multiple bytes for one character (each byte is part of a character?), so I chose an easy way out...

Answer (score 1):

[`FileInputStream#read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read--) reads a single byte of information from the underlying file.

Since these files are text files (according to their extensions), you probably should be using a `FileInputStream`, but a [`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), to properly handle characters, and not the bytes that make them up.

Answer (score 0):

fileinputstream.read() returns "the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached."

You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int))